# Set active tab when navigating from one tab to another by button click

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have been struggling with this for a while now. I'm trying to navigate to one tab (let's say `Home`) to another (let's say `About`). I'm able to navigate that either the page get's added to nav stack, but then it's not changing active tab. That, or then we use `select` to set the active tab, which means that I lose the navigation stack. Here's the latter option code:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  tab: Tabs;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.tab = this.navCtrl.parent;
  } 

  navigate() {
    this.tab.select(1);
  }
```

But this means that as mentioned, I lose the nav stack and can't use the back button that would show if I use `push`. That brings us to the other option, when I use `.push()`:

```
this.navCtrl.push(About)
```

The active tab won't change, but still shows `Home` as the active tab, even though we are successfully navigated to `About` tab.

So what I wish for, is to have both the 'Back' button and the active tab (`About`) selected when I'm clicking the button to go to `About` from `Home`. Here's a demo with the `push` option, as you can see the active tab does not change: https://plnkr.co/edit/6KIL8mxfTMCsvACpiD1K?p=preview

PS. I looked at this question, but it wasn't useful to me: [Changing tabs dynamically in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903456/changing-tabs-dynamically-in-ionic-2)

I'm using Ionic 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is how the tabs component is intended to work. With tabbed navigation you kind of have *n* navigation stacks (where *n* is the number of different tabs you have) which means if you `.push()` a new page on the nav-stack you push it on the stack of the currently selected tab.

Switching to another tab kind of is the same as starting with a new root, you start with the initial page (`[root]="yourFirstPage"`) and can then add new pages to this particular nav-stack (and you can pop them off the nav-stack with a back button).

In you particular example you are trying to `.push()` the *About* page on the stack of the *Home* page and expect the NavController to know that you intended to switch to another stack *and* to push a new page to the new stack.

One solution to your problem could be to always remember the previous tab when you use `.select()` and display back button manually in the navbar which uses `.select(previousTab)` on click.

I hope that makes things clearer for you.

Comment: Sure thanks! Yeah I figured this was default behavior, just wondered that if there is something I can do with some "magical code" (hehe), instead of sort of "hack it".

Comment: I would not even say it's a _hack_ you're just using the publicly available API to build a "tab-switcher" :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's the default behaviour to act like this. When you select a tab it clears the nav stack and set the root to another page. When you push your `about` page when in `home` page you're pushing a new page in your `home` nav stack, this is why it doesn't change and shoudn't change.

The reason to use tabs is that you can segment and divide stuff in they correct categories. When updating a product you don't whant the user the see, for example, billing information in the same stack of `products` since it doesn't belongs to that category.

The `.select()` method (whose you've implemented in your `home.page.ts`) is the closest you can have from beeing able to select a tab without clicking in a specific tab.

What you can do is simply remove `about` from beeing a tab and push it in `home` OR remove the button to go from the home to about page, since there's already a tab for this.

In any case what you want to do is an error that Ionic team removed the possibilities from people doing.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Thanks for confirming that this is intended, I was wondering if I just need to hack it, or if there is actually something that can be done without hacking. But thanks a lot, I can stop wondering now :P Had a tough time choosing which answer to accept. This time I chose David's answer as he presented a hack for this. In my case I can safely use the hack, but in many situations it's not safe, understandably! But thank you and an uppie for you :)