# Can I change the ionic tabs root directory by dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can i change ionic tabs root page when i click dash board?

[image: how can i change ionic tabs root page when i click dash board?]

This my Tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashBoardPage } from '../dash-board/dash-board';
import { TrainingPage } from '../training/training';
import { ArchivePage } from '../archive/archive';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  // tabIndex: Observable<[Number]>;

  dashBoard = DashBoardPage;
  training = TrainingPage;
  archive = ArchivePage;
  home = HomePage;
  constructor(public data: DataProvider) {
    // this.tabIndex = this.data.tabIndex;
  }
}
```

tabs.html

```
<super-tabs selectedTabIndex="{{ tabIndex }}" indicatorColor="dark" [config]="{ sideMenu: 'left', allowElementScroll: 'true' }" tabsPlacement= "bottom">
  <super-tab [root]="home" id="home"  icon="home"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="dashBoard" id="dashBoard" icon="albums"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="training" id="training" icon="information-circle" ></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="archive" id="archive" icon="contacts"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

This my home.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashBoardPage } from '../dash-board/dash-board';
import { TrainingPage } from '../training/training';
import { ArchivePage } from '../archive/archive';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  token: any;
  isLogIn: boolean;
  tabIndex: number ;
  constructor(public data:DataProvider , public appCtrl: App, public storage: Storage,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.isLogIn = true;
  }



  }

  dashBoard() {
    this.navCtrl.push(DashBoardPage, this.token);
    this.storage.set('tabIndex', 1);

  }

  training() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TrainingPage, this.token);
  }

  archive() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ArchivePage, this.token);
  }


}
```

This is my home.html

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar>

          <button item-start class="menu" ion-button="ion-button" icon-only="icon-only" menuToggle>
            <ion-icon style="color: white;" name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <!--
        <img item-end style="width: 100px;" src="assets/imgs/ulogo2.png" alt="">
        -->

    </ion-toolbar>


    </ion-navbar>


</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <br> <br>
  <ion-card (click)="dashBoard()" >
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/das.png">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h1>DashBoard</h1>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card (click)="training()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/training.png">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h1>Training</h1>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card (click)="archive()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="assets/imgs/archive.png">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h1>Archive</h1>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

I want to change tab root when i click dashboard from my home.html it will change the tab root to dashboard page and select dashboard. if press press training it will change to training page and also change the tab root to trainning page ans select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing tabs dynamically in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903456/changing-tabs-dynamically-in-ionic-2)

Answer (score 0):

yea you can inside your tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex={{tabIndex}}>
```

inside your tabs.ts file

```
export class TabsPage {

  // tabIndex: Observable<[Number]>;

  dashBoard = DashBoardPage;
  training = TrainingPage;
  archive = ArchivePage;
  home = HomePage;
  constructor(public data: DataProvider) {
    this.tabIndex = 1;
  }
}
```

in other way instead of using `this.navCtrl.push(TrainingPage, this.token);` use `this.navCtrl.select("1", this.token);`

Comment: thanks for your reply. but this is another page called homePage. this dash board is button is the component of homePage. I want to change from here

Comment: I'm not seeing your footer part in the code i am not understanding where you have given tabs icon which you have mentioned in the code

Comment: updated my question again, this time i added tabs.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164420/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-pc-lover).

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one way to to this & it's by setting the root to the page you want.

```
 dashBoard() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashBoardPage, this.token);
  }
```